# ArrayList in serializable object not carrying over writeUnshared/readUnshared (over network)

Tags: java, networking, arraylist

I am developing a multiplayer game in Java built around my own client-server architecture. In short, the client requests a copy of the server's World object 30 times a second and, upon receiving it, sets its client-side copy to the response. This is all done using Java's standard net API.

The issue I am having is that I also store an ArrayList of Player objects in the world, and when I add a Player to this list, the client doesn't get the update. It still receives a copy of the world from the server, but its not up to date.

I experienced a similar problem in a past project that was caused by write/readObject and **fixed it by using write/readUnshared, but even that isn't working.**

Here's the important stuff from the server end of the communication:

```
String message;
int sum = 0;
while(active)
{
    message = "";
    try {
        message = in.readUTF();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        active = false;
        System.out.println("Lost connection with client " + socket.getInetAddress());
    }

    if(message.equals("GETWORLD"))
    {
        try {
            sum++;
            if(sum == 100)
                main.world.addPlayer(999, 2, 2);
            System.out.println("Client requested world (#" + sum + ")");
            System.out.println(main.world.players.size());
            out.writeUnshared(main.world);
            out.flush();
            System.out.println("Sent client world (#" + sum + ")");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            active = false;
            System.out.println("Lost connection with client " + socket.getInetAddress());
        }
    }

    if(message.equals("DISCONNECT"))
    {
        active = false;
        System.out.println("Client " + socket.getInetAddress() + " requested disconnect");
    }
}
```

And then the client end:

```
Object read = null;
int sum = 0;
while(active)
{
    try {
        Thread.sleep((long)(1000 / 30.0));

        if(connected)
        {
            sum++;
            System.out.println("Asking server for world (#" + sum + ")");
            out.writeUTF("GETWORLD");
            out.flush();

            read = in.readUnshared();
            if(read instanceof World)
            {
                World temp = (World)read;
                System.out.println(temp.players.size());
                frame.panel.updateWorld((World)read);
                System.out.println("Got world from server (#" + sum + ")");
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException | ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        active = false;
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        active = false;
        System.out.println("Lost connection with server @ " + socket.getInetAddress());
        frame.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Obviously the sum variable is for debugging.
I further tested this with some output, here's what is scaring me:

```
Client log:
...
Asking server for world (#99)
1
Got world from server (#99)
Asking server for world (#100)
1
Got world from server (#100)
Asking server for world (#101)
1
Got world from server (#101)
...

Server log:
...
Client requested world (#99)
1
Sent client world (#99)
Client requested world (#100)
2
Sent client world (#100)
Client requested world (#101)
2
Sent client world (#101)
...
```

You can see here that even though the request numbers match up, there's a clear discrepancy between the number of Player objects in the World object.

Here's the important stuff from the World and Player classes for those curious:

```
public class World implements Serializable
{

    public ArrayList<Room> rooms;
    public ArrayList<Player> players;

    private QuickMaths qm;
```

### ...

```
public class Player implements Serializable
{

    private double xPos;
    private double yPos;
    private Color color;

    int id;
    ...
```

I apologize if this is a long yet easy problem. I'm not sure if it's a referencing issue or some other network quirk, but it's really driving me nuts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was about to write you an answer when it was closed. your problem is with writeUnshared. Subobjects are still shared and so the Player is not rewritten. Use the reset method after each write to write a new object.

Comment: Unbelievable-- I have not seen that documented anywhere!! I'll try doing that and see if it works. Thank you. **edit:** using reset() afterwards does in fact work. Problem solved.

Comment: ahhh - I wish they would not close this.... anyway see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUnshared(java.lang.Object)):  "Note that the rules described above only apply to the base-level object written with writeUnshared, and not to any transitively referenced sub-objects in the object graph to be serialized. "

Comment: @JB Nizet I think this one should be reopened. While the solution is about the same the user here relies on writeUnshared which is often misleading. Maybe the title should be edited but I don't think the question should be closed. Anyway your call.

Comment: @zipo13 I've reopened the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with writeUnshared which is a little misleading. 
Read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUnshared(java.lang.Object)):

> "Note that the rules described above only apply to the base-level
>   object written with writeUnshared, and not to any transitively
>   referenced sub-objects in the object graph to be serialized. "

This means that the player object will not be written twice but the old reference to that object in the serialization tree will be used.

The solution to this would be to call the [reset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset()) method after each write call to ensure that the old written objects will not be referenced again.

So:

```
out.writeUnshared(main.world);
out.flush();
out.reset();
```